# Why is android:label not present?

Tags: android

I am making a simple app, and I'm trying to display a label, but it refuses to be visible. Here is the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="r.gabriel.ecuacionesdesegundogrado" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="Ecuación de Segundo Grado">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Ecuación de Segundo Grado">
            <intent-filter android:label="Ecuación de Segundo Grado">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ActivityMain:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/custom_grey" >
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="@string/custom_instructions"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- input a -->
            <TableRow 
                android:weightSum="100">
                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/custom_a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="40"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputA"
                    android:hint="@string/custom_dummyText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="60"/>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- input b -->
            <TableRow 
                android:weightSum="100">
                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/custom_b"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="40"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputB"
                    android:hint="@string/custom_dummyText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="60"/>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- input c -->
            <TableRow 
                 android:weightSum="100">
                 <TextView
                     android:text="@string/custom_c"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="40"/>
                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/inputC"
                     android:hint="@string/custom_dummyText"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="60"/>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- answer -->
            <TableRow 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:weightSum="100" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/custom_solution"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="100"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the android studio preview, the android:label is not displayed, likewise as when run on a physical device and on an emulator.

Comment: Do you want to display "Ecuación de Segundo Grado" when your app launches?

Comment: Yes, for some reason it's not displaying.

Comment: Can you show your MainActivity class code and its XML layout as well?

Comment: @prudhvi There it is.

Comment: You are not using TextView in your onCreate() method to display the text.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to android, what do you mean?

Comment: Did it work? Can you see the title now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for just making your string display when the app launches. Try this. If it works, try adding your TableLayout in the XML layout file.

**ActivityMain.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Ecuación de Segundo Grado");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}
```

Here is the layout file **activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/custom_grey" >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/main_menu"
          android:title="Ecuación de Segundo Grado"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't solve my issue. My problem is  that my action bar does not display the title I set for it in android:label.

Comment: I see, that's what I'm asking where exactly you want to display. I understand now. Let me change it.

Comment: I see your main Activity is not extending "ActionBarActivity". Can you see an Action bar at the top of the screen?

Comment: Yes, it even displays the default icon.

Comment: Then, in your project folders, under res>menu what files do you have

Comment: I have a standard menu_main.xml. Shoul I define the label in there?

Comment: Yes. See the changes I made in my answer. I hope that solves your problem. If not try changing but you have to do it there only. I'm sure about it.

Comment: It only works on a big screen, but your simply creating a menu item. Not a title.

Comment: What do you mean by big screen? Can you see the Actionbar on non-big screens? I think your activity should extend ActionBarActivity and not just Activity.

Comment: Whenever there is overflow, the label text is assigned to the menu button.

Comment: For future googlers, i had to define android:label as an item inside my custom action bar style.